# Magento url rewrite custom formatted product url

Tags: magento-1.9

Does anybody has a proper solution for rewriting Product URL's in the following format:

http://domain/{product_id}_{title}

And furthermore get rid of the prefix Magento pastes before the title in case of duplicates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

YOu just have to change URLs of products and can also use script to edit old products and write a module to update URLs for new products